# call WebMethod with MapPageRoute in jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, web

I want use jQuery Ajax in ASP.Net and i use below code in JavaScript

```
$(function () {
        $('#click').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mine/HelloAgain",
                data: JSON.stringify({ID : 236 , Name : "Milad"}),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

as you see in url i use [mine/HelloAgain] and i create Global for routing in this code

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Mine",
        "mine/{*locale}",
        "~/tst/Test.aspx/HelloAgain",
        true
        );
```

but return 404 Not Found error this WebMethod i want to call

```
[WebMethod]
public static string HelloAgain(int ID, string Name)
{
    return ID.ToString() + " Hello " + Name + DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use method

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Mine",
"mine/{*locale}",
"~/tst/Test.aspx/HelloAgain",
true
);
```

Is is only for mapping page to some route. 
I have found only one solution to map non-Page endpoint: create custom route handler and call it.
For example, Global.asax:

```
routes.Add("Authorization", new Route("Authorization", new GenericRouteHandler<AuthorizationHandler>()));
```

Generic route handler:

```
public class GenericRouteHandler<T> : IRouteHandler where T : IHttpHandler, new()
{
public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    return new T();
}
}
```

Authorization Handler:

```
public class AuthorizationHandler : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var requestData = JsonHelper.DeserializeJson<Dictionary<string, string>>(context.Request.InputStream);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    switch (requestData["methodName"])
    {
        case "Authorize":
            string password = requestData["password"];
            string userName = requestData["name"];
            context.Response.Write(JsonHelper.SerializeJson(Authorize(userName, password)));
            break;
    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get { return true; }
}

public object Authorize(string name, string password)
{
    User user = User.Get(name);
    if (user == null)
        return new { result = "false", responseText = "Frong user name or password!" };
    else
            return new { result = true};
}
```

Also, you can use Reflection to call method, for example:

```
Type thisHandlerType = GetType();
var methodToCall = thisPage.GetMethod(requestData["methodName"]);
if (methodToCall != null)
{
       var response = methodToCall.Invoke(this, new object[]{requestData});
       context.Response.Write(JsonHelper.SerializeJson(response));
}

public object Authorize(Dictionary<string, string> inputData)
{
    User user = User.Get(inputData["name"]);
    if (user == null)
        return new { result = "false", responseText = "Frong user name or password!" };
    else
            return new { result = true};
}
```

[More about custom mapping to custom RouteHandlers](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Mar/28/Custom-ASPNET-Routing-to-an-HttpHandler)